# Specify parameter when assigning value in PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

I have a requirement like: Call a function with 2 parameters in different situations.

```
function => getSum(a, b)
```

here it can be like,

- `a` has value but not `b` then it should be like `getSum(a = value goes here)`
- `b` has value but not `a` then it should be like `getSum(b = value goes here)`
- `a` and `b` have values then it should be like `getSum(a, b)`

`a` and `b` are `uuid`, and `a` and `b` are treated separately in the function.

Is it possible to specify a value to the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you would use default values:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getsum(
   a uuid DEFAULT '...',
   b uuid DEFAULT '...'
) RETURNS ...
```

You can call the function like this:

```
SELECT getsum(b => '...');
```

Then the default value will be used for `a`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will try this.